# How to open JFrame windows sequentially?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am having difficulty having one window open, then, after an event has been handled, having that event open a second, different window. For some reason, after the event has been handled and the first window closed, the second window is not opening up. Any ideas?

Comment: We can't tell you without seeing some code.  NOTE: I hope you're opening the new window as a [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) (or something similar), and *NOT* as another JFrame.  Here's why: [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice/9554657#9554657)

Comment: *"Any ideas"* - You're doing something wrong. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. That's exactly what I needed!

Comment: *"Thank you.."* You who? Tip: Add @paulsm4 (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.